# What is the equivalent in apply_async?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand multiprocessing w/in a class better but the examples I can find use map, not apply_async. I have the map working below, but nothing shows for apply_async. Where am I going wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
    return C.f(*arg,**kwarg)

def unwrap_self_finisher(arg, **kwarg):
    return C.finisher(*arg,**kwarg)

class C:
    def f(self, name):
        print 'hello %s' % name
        return name

    def finisher(self,result):
        print "done"


    def runMap(self):
        print "running Map..."
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        names = ('frank', 'justin', 'osi', 'thomas')
        pool.map(unwrap_self_f, zip([self]*len(names), names))

    def runAsync(self):
        print "running Async..."
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        names = ('frank', 'justin', 'osi', 'thomas')
        for name in names:
            pool.apply_async(unwrap_self_f,args=(name),callback=unwrap_self_finisher) 
        pool.close()
        pool.join()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
    c.runMap()
    c.runAsync()
```

Comment: I think the problem is not the `apply_async` but the fact you're calling methods on the class rather than an object. Try instantiating C first before calling `f`/`finisher`. (Changing `C` to `c` would work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is:

```
def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
    return C.f(*arg,**kwarg) #here you call a CLASS method of C
```

but you define it as a instance method:

```
class C:
    def f(self, name): #self in here, so instance method
        print 'hello %s' % name
        return name
```

Problem with multiprocessing is that you don't get your exceptions on stderr.